# Chaining Retrofit calls with RxJava and returning the main object

Tags: android, retrofit, rx-java

I am trying to use retrofit +rxjava to make nested api calls. Basically I have to construct a List of Library objects. Each Library object has a list of Authors and each Author object has a list of Books. This is how my json is structured.

Library json -

```
{
 title: "Library",
 items: [
      {
        title: "Library1"
        image: "http://example.com/image/101/image_lib1.png"
        url: "http://example.com/api/1"
      },
      {
        title:"Library2"
        image: "http://example.com/image/101/image_lib2.png"
        url: "http://example.com/api/2"
      },
      {
        title:"Library3"
        image: "http://example.com/image/101/image_lib3.png"
        url: "http://example.com/api/3"
      }
   ]
 }
```

And Authors json-

```
{
 title: "Authors",
 items: [
      {
        title: "J.K Rowling"
        image: "http://example.com/image/101/image_author1.png"
        url: "http://example.com/api/101"
      },
      {
        title:"Mark Twain"
        image: "http://example.com/image/101/image_author2.png"
        url: "http://example.com/api/201"
      },
      {
        title:"Charles Dickens"
        image: "http://example.com/image/101/image_author3.png"
        url: "http://example.com/api/301"
      }
   ]
 }
```

And Books json-

```
{
description: Books,
imageurl: "http://example.com/image/101/image_101.png",
items: [
   {
     id: 101,
     title: "Oliver Twist ",
     description: "some description"
   },
  {
   id: 1011,
   title: "Hard times",
   description: "some more description."
  }
}
]
}
```

My api interface is given below.

```
  @GET("/api/")
  Observable<LibraryResponse> getLibraryList();

  @GET("/api/{feedId}")
  Observable<AuthorResponse> getAuthorList(@Path("feedId") String feedId);

  @GET("/api/{feedId}")
  Observable<BooksResponsee> getBooksList(@Path("feedId") String feedId);




Observable<List<Library>> observable = myRestInterface
    .getLibraryList()
    .map(a -> a.getItems())
    .flatMapIterable(b -> b)                 
    .flatMap(h -> myRestInterface                                                                 
                  .getAuthorList(h.getUrl().substring(h.getUrl().lastIndexOf("/") + 1))                                       
                  .map(x -> x.getItems())
                  .flatMapIterable(l -> l)
                  .flatMap(e -> myRestInterface
                                .getBooksList(e.getUrl().substring(e.getUrl().lastIndexOf("/") + 1))
                                .map(d -> d.getItems())
                                .flatMapIterable(c -> c)))

    .collect(// ? into list of main object)
    .doOnNext(mainObjectList -> new ViewupdateMethod(mainObjectList));
    .subscribe(...);
```

I am trying to construct one Librarylist object that I can use to update my UI. I am kind of stuck here. After making the multiple calls, how do I save the results back and collect everything to a list of library object?

Comment: May be you should try `.toList()` ?

Comment: Why do you need to request authors and their books if you're only interested in libraries? If you need something like SQL join here, then you need to construct another class, LibraryWithAuthorsWithBooks

Comment: @KirillGamazkov, My Library POJO contains List<Authors> and Author POJO contains LIst of Books. So I need to populate everything and get the Library object

Comment: Please attach LibraryResponse#getItems(), AuthorResponse#getItems() and BookResponse#getItems() method signatures. If *Response.getItems() returns List<*Pojo>, then I wonder why your REST interface doesn't fill those lists with appropriate objects for you

Comment: By the way, you can replace `.map(a -> a.getItems()).flatMapIterable(b -> b)` with `.flatMapIterable(a -> a.getItems())`

Comment: One-letter variables are awful, but I think I've managed to solve this. See my answer below

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
    Observable<List<Library>> observable = myRestInterface
            .getLibraryList()
            .flatMapIterable(response -> response.getItems())
            .doOnNext(library -> myRestInterface
                    .getAuthorList(library.getUrl().substring(library.getUrl().lastIndexOf("/") + 1))
                    .flatMapIterable(response -> response.getItems())
                    .doOnNext(author -> library.getAuthors().add(author))
                    .doOnNext(
                            author -> myRestInterface
                                    .getBooksList(author.getUrl().substring(author.getUrl().lastIndexOf("/") + 1))
                                    .flatMapIterable(response -> response.getItems())
                                    .doOnNext(book -> author.getBooks().add(book))
                                    .subscribe()
                    )
                    .subscribe()
            )

            .doOnNext(mainObjectList -> new ViewupdateMethod(mainObjectList))
            .subscribe();
```

Note `.subscribe()` calls. They are used to start execution of the whole chain. RxObservable does nothing until subscriber arrives.

Comment: How do you retry your second subscribe if status is failed? for example I need to check the status of my request from the server and if I got "waiting  status" then I need to send back a request again until I get a "proceed status" and then proceed with the last subscribe process.

Comment: I'm not quite sure I'm following you. RxJava offers many methods to deal with retrying, starting with Observable#retry and a couple of others. If none of them seems to fit your needs, you can incapsulate retrying logic into your 'myRestInterface.getLibraryList()', or extract it to reusable code piece and use it together with Observable#compose

Comment: tl;dr - basically, you can just put .retry() just before .subscribe(), does this do the trick for you?

Comment: Hi Kirill, I used flatmap() and then use repeatWhen()  for the inner observable and it is working.  Thanks!